# WPF Core DependencyInjection Scoped

Tags: wpf, dependency-injection, scopes

I have the following projects:

1. .Net Standard 2.0 Service Lib
2. Asp.Net Web API Project
3. WPF Core 3.1 App

The plan was to share the Service layer between the API and the WPF App.
In the Web API I add a scoped UnitOfWork Service that itself uses scoped DbContexts

```
services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
```

The Service Layer uses the UnitOfWork for committing several queries across services (which are added scoped was well) in one transaction. This works as expected.

Service1:

```
public Service1(IService2 service2,IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
{
     ...
}
public async DoSomething()
{
    _unitOfWork.DBContext.SomeTable.Add(new SomeTableRecord())
    _service2.AddSomeDbRecord(saveInstant:false); //adds a record in another table without saving
    await _unitOfWork.SaveAllChanges(); //saves both db changes (inserts) in one transaction
}
```

Service 2:

```
public Service2(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
{
     ...
}
public async AddSomeDbRecord(bool saveInstant)
{
    _unitOfWork.DBContext.SomeTable2.Add(new SomeTable2Record())
    if(saveInstant)
      await _unitOfWork.SaveAllChanges(); //saves both db changes (inserts) in one transaction
}
```

Now when adding my WPF Project where I don't have the Scope of a "WebRequest" anymore, what is a good way to define the scope. Ideally i would like the scope to be around the full chain of calls to a Services method.

I believe this would do what I wanted it to do:

```
 using (var serviceScope = Host.Services.CreateScope())
 {
       var services = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;


       var service1 = services.GetRequiredService<Service1>();

       service1.DoSomething();
 }
```

...but this is obviously not nice or straightforward to write for every call to the service lib and I cannot use ViewModel Constructor Injection for the services.

A scope per ViewModel Instance would be okay too I guess but I don't know how to do this (I'm using MVVM Pattern with a ViewModelLocator)

I would want to stay with Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection as the DI framework as this is also what I'm using in the ASP.Net Project.